# JavaScript alternative to associative array

Tags: javascript

I have no experience in javaScript, but i have to write a simple server app. What i need is to describe a connected client by:

```
1. name
2. socket
3. connectedSocket
```

The way that by:

```
1. just having information about socket, i can get its associated name and connectedSocket
2. just having a name i can get its socket.
```

I want to avoid using "find" functions to get a certain client by searching for specified name or other socket since it's a server app. I thought about using associative array since i can just get value by giving a key, but i heard in javascript it's just an object and

```
delete myArray["key"];
```

will not reduce array size. So, in summary, i need to represent that data the way that i can avoid using "find" functions and being able to remove and add a lot of connections in a safe manner.

Comment: What is the problem of using an object?

Comment: I'm re-reading the question and I'm even more confused. When you say `delete myArray["key"];` do you mean an *actual* array or an object? The latter would be akin to an associative array in PHP. And what do you mean the line doesn't reduce the array size? If it's an actual array then the *length* wouldn't be touched but it's size *in memory* would be reduced. If that's an object, then deleting a key won't change a "size" because objects have none - no length property or equivalent. Memory size would still be reduced.

Comment: An object does not have an "array size". It is an object, not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jacascript objects basically *are* associative arrays. So most likely they're the correct tool for you.

I'm not entirely clear what you're wanting to do with `delete` that you think it won't do. If you're wanting to know how many keys are in an object, you can find out using Object.keys, and `delete`ing from the object will reduce that value. For example:

```js
const myObject = {
  a: 'hello',
  b: 'world',
}

console.log('a before', myObject.a); // can also access it with myObject["a"] if needed
console.log('length before', Object.keys(myObject).length);

delete myObject.a

console.log('a after', myObject.a);
console.log('length after', Object.keys(myObject).length);
```

If you're concerned that delete does not free up memory, it will, as long as there are no other references to the thing that was deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly I would do something like this:
Get a unique id for each socket connection and then you can create an object like this:

```
const socketStore = {
   [socketId]: {
       ...
   },
   [socketId]: {
     ...
   }
}
```

Then in order to retrieve data you can use `socketStore[socketId]` and in order to delete data you can use `delete socketStore[socketId]`